# Lagrange Interpolation with a given function in C++

Tags: c++, math, interpolation, numeric

My function is defined as f(x) = (x^2+1)^-1 on the interval [-5,5]. I am trying to interpolate this function by using equally spaced n nodes (e.g. n=5 implies 10/5 =2, your delta X, meaning x-values are -5,-3,-1,1,3, and 5 for the degree 5 polynomial).

I am asking my code to do the following:

1. Calculate f(x) for each x (i.e. divide the length of the interval, 10, by a large number h and stored them into the array x[500]. Similarly, y[500] stores the y's). You can [see](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iX2IGUN4aMKYcHTkc4MO2PhTn96Fg1OLXb10byqDtzU/edit?usp=sharing) that the code is doing this fine from Column A and B (i.e., h is 200. So, 10/200 is .05 and you can see the x's and y's being correct values).
2. Calculate P_n(x) for each x (i.e. given user input of n, say 5, use Lagrange method to figure out P_5(x) for each x). The code is taking in user input of n value and calculates interpolating points correctly (e.g. when n=5, under "//TEST", x=-5, -3, -1,1,3,5 and y=-.0384615, .1, .5, .5, .1, and -.0384615. These values are correct).

I believe the error is with the nested loops because you can [see](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iX2IGUN4aMKYcHTkc4MO2PhTn96Fg1OLXb10byqDtzU/edit?usp=sharing) (Column B and the graph) that the polynomial grows exponentially and then plateaus, whereas it should 1) oscillate near the both end of the endpoints the interval, and 2) have a similar shape to the f(x) (e.g. upside down "U" in the middle of the interval).

The error between the approximating polynomial and function is supposed to be large, but not as large as 46.1 vs .039 at x=4.95 for n=5. The [correct graph](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iX2IGUN4aMKYcHTkc4MO2PhTn96Fg1OLXb10byqDtzU/edit?usp=sharing) is shown in the link (the one that's below).

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//THIS PROGRAM USES LAGRANGE INTERPOLATION
int main ()
{
    float userN;
    float deltaX, deltaXP, xp;
    float x[500], y[500],xP[50], yF[50], yP[500];
    float p, yp=0;
    float h=200;
    
    deltaX=10/h;
    x[0]=-5;
    y[0]=1/((x[0]*x[0])+1);
    for (int i=0; i<=h; i++)
    {
        x[i+1] = x[i]+deltaX;
        y[i+1] = 1/((x[i+1]*x[i+1])+1);
    }

    cout << "Select your desired nodes (degree n - you have 5, 11,21, and 41 to choose from):"<<endl;
    cin >> userN;
    if (userN==5 || userN==11 || userN==21 || userN==41)
    {
        deltaXP = 10/userN;
        xP[0]=-5;
        yF[0] = 1/((xP[0]*xP[0])+1);
        for (int i=0; i<=userN; i++)
        {
            xP[i+1] = xP[i]+deltaXP;
            yF[i+1] = 1/((xP[i+1]*xP[i+1])+1);
        }//TEST
            cout <<i<<" th x-value for p is: "<<xP[i]<<endl;
            cout <<i<<" th y-value for p is: "<<yF[i]<<endl;

        for (int i = 0; i<=h; i++)
        {
            xp=x[i];
            for (int j=0; j<=userN; j++)
            {
                p = 1;
                for (int k=0; k<=userN; k++)
                {
                    if (xP[j] != xP[k])
                    {
                        {
                            p = p* (xp - xP[k])/(xP[j] - xP[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                yp = yp+p*yF[j];
            }
            yP[i]=yp;
        }

        cout <<"*****The P(x_i) values for P are below*****"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<=h; i++)
        {
            cout <<yP[i]<<endl;
        }//use the similar loop to cout x and f(x) values
    }else {cout <<"You entered the wrong number of n. Exiting the program"<<endl;}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: ***Right now, it is not correct*** Can you be way more specific? Are the values way off, random looking, or just a little bit off, something else? Do you have any values you can share?

Comment: @drescherjm The values are way off and the polynomial is not oscillating correctly. Here is the link to the table of data currently: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iX2IGUN4aMKYcHTkc4MO2PhTn96Fg1OLXb10byqDtzU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it, instead of responding in comments. The question should be clear without reading the comments. I'm no expert on this topic, but I think it might help if you specify some input, output and expected output, instead of reading data from cin. Reading from cin just complicates the code and others have to guess or reverse engineer what the correct input is. A [mre] should be as short and simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> e.g. when n=5, under "//TEST", x=-5, -3, -1,1,3,5 and y=**-.0384615**, .1, .5, .5, .1, and **-.0384615**. These values are correct.

Well, actually the correct values should be all *positive* and that's what the posted code does.

It would be more readable (and testable and mantainable) to put the evaluation of the Lagrange polynomials (and not only that) in a function or even a `class`, but the main flaw of this program is that it doesn't reset `yp` every time it starts the sum, so that it accumulates.

```cpp
// ...
int main ()
{
    //...
    float p, yp=0; // <- Ok, but only the first time.

    //...
    for (int i = 0; i<=h; i++)
    {
        xp=x[i];
        
        //    <---------------------------- Here you should have    yp = 0;

        for (int j=0; j<=userN; j++)
        {
            p = 1;                       // Just as this variable is resetted.
            for (int k=0; k<=userN; k++)
            {
                // ... Updates p...
                yp = yp + p * yF[j];     // Update yp.
            }
            yP[i]=yp;
        }
    // ...
}
```